cross-origin cookies problem between nextjs and express
i have project composed of nextjs as a frontEnd and express as a backEnd, and they have different server and i was trying to set-cookie token in express to nextjs when i login and i have this code in back end to handle login process .
i have project composed of nextjs as a frontEnd and express as a backEnd, and they have different server and i was trying to set-cookie token in express to nextjs when i login and i have this code in back end to handle login process .
const login = (req, res, next) => {

   const result = validationResult(req);
   if (!result.isEmpty()) {
      return RESPONSE.errorHandler(res, 500, result.array()[0]["msg"]);
   }
   let { userName, password, secretKey } = req.body;

   pool.query(
      "SELECT company_id,company_name,company_password,security_key,room_ID FROM company WHERE company_name = ?",
      userName,
      (error, result, fields) => {
         if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            next(AppError.create(error, 500, "database Error"));
         }
         if (result.length > 0) {

            compare(password, result[0]["company_password"], (err, resul) => {

               if (err){
                  console.log('compar...',err);
                  next(AppError.create(error, 500, "database Error"));
               } 
               if (resul) {
                  if(result[0]["security_key"] === secretKey) {
                  const token = createToken({
                     id: result[0]["company_id"],
                     userName: result[0]["company_name"],
                  });
               
                  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development")
                  res.cookie("token", token, {
                     secure: true,
                     httpOnly: true,
                     sameSite:"lax",
                     domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
                     path: "/en/company",
                     maxAge: 86400000,
                  });
                  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
                     res.cookie("token", token, {
                        secure: true,
                        httpOnly: true,
                        sameSite: "none",
                        domain: ".tasker-client-steel.vercel.app",
                        path: "/en/company",
                        maxAge: 86400000,
                     });



                  res.cookie("roomId", result[0]["room_ID"], {
                     // secure: true,
                     // httpOnly: true,
                     sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "lax" : "none",
                     // domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
                     domain: ".tasker-client-steel.vercel.app",
                     path: "/en/company",
                     maxAge: 86400000,
                  });

                  RESPONSE.successHandler(res, 200, {
                     id: result[0]["company_id"],
                     userName: result[0]["company_name"],
                     cookies: res.getHeaders()['set-cookie']
                  });
                  return;
                  }
                  RESPONSE.errorHandler(res, 401, 
                     'the secret key is not correct'
                  );
                  return;
               }
               RESPONSE.errorHandler(res, 401, 
                  'the password is not correct'
               );
            });
         } else {
               RESPONSE.errorHandler(res, 500, 
               'the user name is not exists'
               );
         }

      }
   );
};

and this code in fronEnd login
function handleFormSubmition(e,isSecretKey,setErrorMessage,setErrorText,router,setLoader,...data) {
   e.preventDefault();
   setLoader(true);
   if(isSecretKey) {
      let companyJsonData = {
         userName:data[0],
         password:data[1],
         secretKey:data[2],
      };
      fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/en/login/company`,{
         method:"post",
      credentials: 'include',
      headers:{
         "content-type":"application/json",
         "cache-control":"no-cache",
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(companyJsonData)
      }).then(res=>{
         return res.json();
      }).then(data=>{
         if(data.status === 'fail' || data.status === 'error' ) {
            setErrorMessage(true);
            setErrorText(data?.message);
            setLoader(false);
         } else {
            setErrorMessage(false);
            // socket.connect();
            // socket.emit('user',data.data);
            router.push('/en/company');
            console.log(data)
         }
      }).catch(err=>{
         console.log(err);
         setLoader(false);
      })
   } else {
      let personalJsonData = {
         userName:data[0],
         password:data[1],
      };
      fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/en/login/user`,{
         method:"post",
      credentials: 'include',
      headers:{
         "content-type":"application/json",
         "cache-control":"no-cache",
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(personalJsonData)
      }).then(res=>{
         return res.json();
      }).then(data=>{
         if(data.status === 'fail' || data.status === 'error' ) {
            setErrorMessage(true);
            setErrorText(data?.message);
            setLoader(false)
         } else {
            if(data.data.redirect) {
               router.push('/en/login/admin');
            } else {
               // socket.connect();
               // socket.emit('user',data.data);
               router.push('/en/user');
            }
            setErrorMessage(false);
            console.log(data);
         }
      }).catch(err=>{
         console.log(err);
         setLoader(false);
      })
   }
}```


When i was working locally every things was be good, the cookies sending from express and stored in frontend.
but When i uploading project to production, when i login it is responding me success login but the cookies not sending from express to next, although i implemented all the correct options to communicate between different domain.


its getting me this error in browser devtool:
this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.


i upload nextjs to vercel and express to render.

//////////////////////////////////////////

this frontend code in github [https://github.com/alazy11/tasker-client](https://github.com/alazy11/tasker-client).

this backend code in github [https://github.com/alazy11/tasker-server](https://github.com/alazy11/tasker-server)



i trying to send cookies token from express back end to nextjs frontend , but the cookies not sending

